# Problem with PostgreSQL

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

I'm trying load pg_trgm module to PostgreSQL, but something going wrong:

```
$ psql -d simko_development -f /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql
SET
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:9: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:14: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:19: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:24: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:29: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:38: ERROR:  function similarity_op(text, text) does not exist
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:44: NOTICE:  type "gtrgm" is not yet defined
DETAIL:  Creating a shell type definition.
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:44: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:49: ERROR:  type gtrgm does not exist
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:55: ERROR:  function gtrgm_in(cstring) does not exist
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:61: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:66: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:71: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:76: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:81: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:86: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:91: ERROR:  type gtrgm does not exist
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:105: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text % text
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:111: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:116: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:121: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
psql:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share/contrib/pg_trgm.sql:132: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text % text
```

- Mac OS X 10.6.6
- PostgreSQL 9.0.2 (insalled via Homebrew)

More info:

```
$ pg_config --sharedir
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.2/share
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling PostgreSQL solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Can't help you with macos, but the same probblem often occurs on debian-linux installations. A solution there is very simple: required libraries are located in a separate package, named `postgresql-contrib`, which should be installed additionally to the main `postgresql` package.

Comment: On production server I also did this and module was successful installed. On dev machine I have contrib folder with needed modules, but it don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old question, but i found it using Google, so others might end up here as well.

On my Mac OSX macports install, i had two folders with .so files for postgresql:

```
/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/
```

and

```
/usr/local/pgsql-9.0/lib/
```

It seems like my installation looked in /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/ and not in /usr/local/pgsql-9.0/lib/, so to install pg_trgm, i had to do the following:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/pg_trgm.so /usr/local/pgsql-9.0/lib/
```

This should work with any .so file which is not in the right place.

Comment: this answer help me to solve the same issue; btw on my OSX 10.7 Lion Server setup the symlink to create is: sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/pg_trgm.so /usr/lib/postgresql/ ; I find  pg_trm.so by hotspot and > pg_config --pkglibdir to find the path of the .so folder ( /usr/lib/postgresql )